# Is possible to re allocate the heap memory in Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am developing an application in that I am getting the Out of memory Exception this is happened due to the insufficient memory. Is possible re allocate the memory once reach the maximum allocate memory.

Comment: If I were in you, I'll try to understand why I am getting OOM in the first place,

Comment: Read docs and guides on how to avoid OOM and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to allocate more memory than is in budget which system gives you.
You can try to put android:largeHeap to your manifest, but it works only on some devices and it isnt generally best solution. 
Instead you should find out where you are using all that memory and try to optimize to cut it down.
On modern devices there should be plenty of memory and should be enough for most operations with good design. System places gap on memory usage to prevent poorly designed apps, from depleting memory pool.